# I have a worksheet that does not populate in certain cells or has errors (ie #DIV/0!), I think it is my function statement

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that does not populate in certain cells or has errors (i.e. `#DIV/0!`) I have validated the data is there on other ref tabs in the workbook but **I believe the functions to be wrong**, they **work on some cells but not the others surrounding it**. I have intermediate skills in excel and the functions being used are unfamiliar to me.

This the function that I am using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2='ShippedQtyPrivate-Input'!$B$2:$B$818)*
            ('ShippedQtyPrivate-Input'!$A$2:$A$818=BR$2)*
            ($A16='ShippedQtyPrivate-Input'!$C$1:$H$1)*
            ('ShippedQtyPrivate-Input'!$C$2:$H$818))
```

**But every 1st - 4th column after a populated column has no data**. I don't understand why it doesn't work on all columns.

Comment: The error indicates you're trying to divide by 0.  Add an example function that is giving the error so someone can help you out.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(BM122,0,$G$1-8,1,8),OFFSET($BM$14,0,$G$1-8,1,8))/SUM(OFFSET($BM$14,0,$G$1-8,1,8))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to handle the error. If you just want the cell to show the text 'Error' then the following should work:

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(BM122,0,$G$1-8,1,8),OFFSET($BM$14,0,$G$1-8,1,8))/SUM(OFFSET($‌​BM$14,0,$G$1-8,1,8)),"Error")`

Comment: Excel has the `IFERROR` function to prevent this exact sort of double typing of the result.